# Get total earnings from 3 tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have `users` table and 3 tables with user earnings.
What I am trying to do is selecting the top 10 users with the most earnings based on those 3 tables.
I am struggling with this request since yesterday and I cannot make it to work.
I want to sum those 3 earning tables as total.

Any help on this please?

```
SELECT 
    users.first_name, 
    users.last_name,
    (select SUM(`value`) from `earnings1`  where users.id = earnings1.user)  as earnings1,
    (select SUM(`value`) from `earnings2`  where users.id = earnings2.user)  as earnings2,
    (select SUM(`value`) from `earnings3`  where users.id = earnings3.user)  as earnings3,
    (earnings1 + earnings2 + earnings3) as total    
FROM users   
GROUP BY users.id
ORDER BY total DESC    
LIMIT 10
```

The error I am getting right now is:

> Unknown column 'earnings1' in 'field list'

Comment: What's the error you are getting?

Comment: right now `Unknown column 'earnings1' in 'field list' `

Comment: And what are columns in table `earnings1`?

Comment: `earnings1` contains `id` , `value`, `user` columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
select first_name, last_name, 
(earnings1 + earnings2 + earnings3) total from
(select users.id, users.first_name, users.last_name,
(select sum(`value`) from `earnings1` where users.id = earnings1.user) as earnings1,
(select sum(`value`) from `earnings2` where users.id = earnings2.user) as earnings2,
(select sum(`value`) from `earnings3` where users.id = earnings3.user) as earnings3
from users group by 1,2,3) t
order by 3 desc limit 10
```

**t** is the name you give the resultset from the inner query. it is somewhat similar to a common table expression but not precisely. MySQL mandates you to give this resultset a name.

**1,2,3** you can either user 1,2,3 or you can use column names **users.id, users.first_name, users.last_name** as your grouping columns. 1,2,3 means the first, second and third columns in your select statement.

Comment: Thank you for your answer :) Could you please tell me where `1,2,3` comes from?  And this `t` , is it the same like `AS t`?

Comment: @divHelper11 - I have made the edit, please check now.